# Ambiguous linear congruence question from Niven

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am *not* looking for a solution, I need help reading this problem. From Niven's The theory of Numbers (4th edition):

Suppose $(a, m) = 1$, and $ax_1 = 1$ (mod m). For s = 1, 2, ..., let $x_s = 1/a - (1/z)(1 - ax_1)^s$. Prove $x_s$ is an integer and $ax_s = 1$ (mod $m^s$).

I don't understand what z is supposed to be in the definition of $x_s$.

Edit: Included a picture, it's problem ten. It's one part of the three problems 10, 11 and 12.

[image: Picture of problem]

Comment: This is hard to parse.  do you mean  $x_s=\frac 1a - \frac {(1-ax_1)^s}z$?  Sure doesn't look like an integer.  (even if we assume $z=m$ as seems probable).

Comment: Can you type the problem exactly as it appears, with no edits?  Maybe include a picture?

Comment: I wrote down that definition verbatim, your formatting is how I would read it.

Comment: Well, I kind of think $z=a$.  With that choice at least we get $x_1=\frac 1a\times \left(1-(1-ax_1)\right)=x_1$ so consistency requires $z=a$.  Try $x_2$ and see if it makes sense.

Comment: Note:  taking $z=a$ it is obvious that $x_s$ is an integer (just expand $(1-ax)^s$ and note that only the initial $1$ is not divisible by $a$.  I'm pretty sure I have it right.

Comment: That guess correctly gives $x_2$, I think you're correct as well. You might post your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is simply a typo, and that $z=a$.

My evidence:  using that formula with $s=1$, and of course requiring that we get $x_1$ back forces $z=a$.  Also, it is a simple induction to show that with $z=a$ all of the $x_s$ are integers.

Comment: For future readers, I was able to prove the problem with this change.